# Column Search in DataTables using Server-side Processing COLDFUSION

Tags: jquery, datatables, coldfusion

I have managed to create your "Column Search in DataTables using Server-side Processing" in COLDFUSION.

When the page loads the first time, the correct data (refer to fig 1) and the log (refer to fig 2) are properly populated

When search criteria business13 is typed in column CONTACT, the log screen shows the appropriate data (see fig 3). However, the datatable screen is not refreshed with the data returned from the ajax call (see fig 4).

Below please find the .cfm and .cfc code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href=https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css />
  <script src=https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js></script>


    <title>Column Search in DataTables using Server-side Processing</title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('#tbl-contact thead th').each(function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html(title+' <input type="text" class="col-search-input" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
            });
            
            var table = $('#tbl-contact').DataTable({
                   "scrollX": true,
                  "pagingType": "numbers",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                //"ajax": "../dataTableColumnFilterCFC.cfc?method=postRegmasterAjax10",

            "ajax": {
                "url": "../dataTableColumnFilterCFC.cfc?method=postRegmasterAjax10",
                
                 dataSrc: function ( receivedData ) {
                   console.log(receivedData); // Here you can know that the data has been received
                   return receivedData;
                 },  
                error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    console.log('here you can track the error');
                 }                                      
                
              },                  
                
                
                
                
                
                order: [[2, 'asc']],
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: "_all",
                    orderable: false
                 }]
            });

            table.columns().every(function () {
                var table = this;
                $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (table.search() !== this.value) {
                          table.search(this.value).draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="datatable-container">
        <h2>Column Search in DataTables using Server-side Processing</h2>
        <table name="tbl-contact" id="tbl-contact" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">   

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Ticket</th>
                    <th>Contact</th>
                    <th>Contract</th>
                    <th>Classification</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Accountable</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                    <th>Received</th>
                    <th>SLA DUE</th>
                    <th>Weekno</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
Select allOpen in new window

<cfcomponent displayname="Generate HTML" output="true">


    <cffunction name="postRegmasterAjax10" access="remote" format="json">
        <cfparam name="url.sEcho" default="1" type="integer" />
        <cfparam name="url.iDisplayStart" default="0" type="integer" />
        <cfparam name="url.iDisplayLength" default="10" type="integer" />
        <cfparam name="url.sSearch" default="" type="string" />
        <cfparam name="url.iSortingCols" default="0" type="integer" />

 

      <cfset LOCAL.search_value       =  url['search[value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sSearchTicket       = url['columns[1][search][value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sSearchContact    = url['columns[2][search][value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sSearchContract    = url['columns[3][search][value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sClassification    = url['columns[4][search][value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sSearchDescription = url['columns[5][search][value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sSearchStatus       = url['columns[6][search][value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sSearchAccountable   = url['columns[7][search][value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sSearchCount      = url['columns[8][search][value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sSearchReceived    = url['columns[9][search][value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sSearchSlaDue       = url['columns[10][search][value]']>
      <cfset LOCAL.sSearchWeekno       = url['columns[11][search][value]']>
   

        <cfset listColumns = "pmId,pmTicketNumber,sContactName,contractNumber,sClassification,pmComment1,sStatus,sStatusAccountable,sRegDate,nSlaDays,sSlaDueDate,nDaysOverdue" />   
        <cfset listColumns = "pmId,pmTicketNumber,sContactName,contractNumber,sClassification,pmComment1,sStatus,sStatusAccountable,pmCount,sRegDate,sSlaDueDate,nWeekNo" />   
        
        <cfset sIndexColumn = "pmId" />


      <cfset var MYVAR = structNew()>
      <cfset MYVAR.sQuery = ''>
      <cfset MYVAR.sQueryCount = ''>
      <cfset MYVAR.nIdx = 0>

      
   
      <cfsavecontent variable="MYVAR.sQuery" >
         select 
            *
         from
            postRegMasterA
      </cfsavecontent>




        <cfquery  name="qFiltered" result="clyde">
         #PreserveSingleQuotes(MYVAR.sQuery)#
         where
         sContactName    like   <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="%#trim(LOCAL.sSearchContact)#%">
        </cfquery> 

  

      <cfset MYVAR.nIdx = findNoCase('from',MYVAR.sQuery)>
      <cfset MYVAR.sQueryCount = 'select count(*) as total  ' & mid(MYVAR.sQuery, MYVAR.nIdx, 10000)>
      <cfquery name = 'qcount'>
         #PreserveSingleQuotes(MYVAR.sQueryCount)#
      </cfquery>      



        <cfcontent reset="Yes" />
        {"sEcho": <cfoutput>#val(url.sEcho)#</cfoutput>,
        "iTotalRecords": <cfoutput>#qCount.total#</cfoutput>,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": <cfoutput>#qFiltered.recordCount#</cfoutput>,
        "aaData": [
            <cfoutput query="qFiltered" startrow="#val(url.iDisplayStart+1)#" maxrows="#val(url.iDisplayLength)#">
                <cfif currentRow gt (url.iDisplayStart+1)>,</cfif>
                [<cfloop list="#listColumns#" index="thisColumn"><cfif thisColumn neq listFirst(listColumns)>,</cfif><cfif thisColumn is "version"><cfif version eq 0>"-"<cfelse>"#replacenocase(jsStringFormat(version),"\'","'","all")#"</cfif><cfelse>"#replacenocase(jsStringFormat(qFiltered[thisColumn][qFiltered.currentRow]),"\'","'","all")#"</cfif></cfloop>]
            </cfoutput> ] }



    </cffunction>


</cfcomponent>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you want to filter and not search. Based on the images, it seems you don't want to perform a new Search, it seems like you want to filter and show just matching rows. Is that the case? See this example: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html

Comment: Yes - I want to filter. However, when I filter, the screen does not refresh